# Is there a tool to make bread balls?

Tags: bread, equipment

I’d like to make bread balls out of already baked soft and moist bread. The tool that I have in mind is akin to an ice cream scoop, but sharpened and thinner (since bread is much softer than frozen cream).

Is there a specialized tool for just that or a technique that would allow to form bread balls avoiding compression (and thus thickening)?

Comment: It might be easier to use uncooked bread dough and make little tiny rolls.  (I make a few hundred of them each year for monkey bread for christmas morning ... although you'd want a single layer, and spaced out some so they don't end up too dense)

Comment: I plan to serve the balls alongside curry-like sauces. Crust is undesirable.

Comment: Is there something wrong with cubes?  that's the normal bread treatment for fondue.  You'd have better luck trying to figure out something that would grind off the corners of the cubes to make them more round than trying to find something to slice into the bread like a melon baller.  Or try the various tricks for pealing potatoes, but set up to remove the crusts from rolls.

Comment: Cubes would work, just not the way I’d like to serve them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't imagine anything would be sharp enough - you have to saw it with a sharp serrated knife to just slice it.

Only think I could think would be maybe to try it frozen with a melon-baller or similar, but it would have to be really soft beforehand - sawing at frozen bread is even harder than at room temperature - but it might prevent compression.